# Play/Stream audio from a golang project

Tags: go, streaming

I am trying to play/stream an audio file (.gsm) from aws s3management. I can't find an sdk to do this. My first question would be, Is there something but I can not find it?

The second part, If there isn't one could I get around it by downloading the file to a temp file and playing from there?

If part 2 is true then what would i use to do this and how would I implement this.

Comment: I haven't looked into what kind of media playback libraries Go offers but I'd be surprised if much exists. If you don't find one I'd recommend using `ffmpeg`. You can just invoke it as a command line process, it's a small file, easy enough to include in your distro and plays most formats. I've used it a couple times to deliver video in desktop apps with satisfactory results.